# Can someone explain how the reduce method is working in this Functional JavaScript challenge?

Tags: javascript

According to the documentation of reduce..

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

And this is the task:

> Given an Array of strings, use Array#reduce to create an object that
>   contains the number of times each string occured in the array. Return
>   the object directly (no need to console.log).
>
> ### Example

```
 var inputWords = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Durian', 'Durian', 'Durian']

 console.log(countWords(inputWords))

   // =>
    // {
    //   Apple: 2,
    //   Banana: 1,
    //   Durian: 3
    // }
```

This is the solution:

```
function countWords(inputWords){
  return inputWords.reduce(function(wordCount, currentValue){
    if (!wordCount[currentValue]){
      wordCount[currentValue] = 1;
    } else {
      wordCount[currentValue] = wordCount[currentValue] + 1;
    }
    return wordCount;
  },{});
}

module.exports = countWords;
```

Isn't each indice in the array a 'string'? How is the object being created? I get how the iterator is being achieved, but can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: The object is created by the two-character object literal `{}`, which is supplied as the initial accumulator value of the `reduce` operation. Each iteration, that accumulator object is either given a new property named by the string under consideration (and given an initial value of 1), or the existing property is increased by one. Is any particular part of that explanation unclear to you?

Comment: Also read the MDN documentation on [Array.prototype.reduce() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Note that this code isn't very good at counting the word "constructor". `:)` (N.B. This has nothing to do with your question, but is a bug caused by the overly-general test `if (!wordCount[currentValue])`, which counts inherited property `constructor` as an already-seen word.)

Comment: `},{});` is equivalent to `}, new Object());`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every call of the function passes the last result, `wordCount`, and the current element of the array.  The second parameter of reduce passes the initial value of `wordCount`, which in this case is an empty object literal.

Reduce will call the function for each element.  With each call `wordCount` is updated and returned and passed as `wordCount` on the next call.  *Updating `wordCount`in the function won't effect `wordCount`on the next call, what ever is returned is what will be set to `wordCount` on the next call*.

Here's how it looks with each pass (values and variables shortened from example to fit):

```
index | curVal | wordCount                        | (returned)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0     | 'App'  | { }                              | {'App':1}    
1     | 'Ban'  | { 'App': 1 }                     | {'App':1,'Ban':1}   
2     | 'App'  | { 'App': 1, 'Ban': 1 }           | {'App':2,'Ban':1}   
3     | 'Dur'  | { 'App': 2, 'Ban': 1 }           | {'App':2,'Ban':1,'Dur':1 }
4     | 'Dur'  | { 'App': 2, 'Ban': 1, 'Dur': 1 } | {'App':2,'Ban':1,'Dur':2 }
5     | 'Dur'  | { 'App': 2, 'Ban': 1, 'Dur': 2 } | {'App':2,'Ban':1,'Dur':3 }
```

The value returned is `{ 'Apple': 2, 'Banana': 1, 'Durian': 3 }`

Answer (score 3):

The reduce function takes two parameters:

1. Callback(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array)
2. Initial value

Whatever value is returned from the callback function is then passed in to the callback function in the `wordCount` position.

In this example ... your `currentValue` is initialized with an object literal (second parameter of the `reduce` function).

After that ... it returns the updated object literal every time and thus, builds it's state.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

A good way to see the state being built is to put a console.log at the end of the callback function.

Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/efw62Lg3/) (and look at the Debugger console).

Comment: "Whatever value is returned from the callback function is then passed in to the callback function in the `currentValue` position." should be `wordCount` instead of `currentValue`. `currentValue` is the current array element in `inputWords`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument passed to reduce is the "initialValue", and you are passing {} (an instance of an empty object). On each call to your function, "wordCount" will be this object. In JavaScript, you can reference properties of an object with bracket/string notation like this:

```
someObject["someProperty"] = 2;
// ...is the same as
someObject.someProperty = 2;
```

So, if you were to peek in on your first and third iterations of your function, they would look something like this:

```
if (!wordCount["Apple"]){
  // On first iteration, wordCount.Apple will be undefined, so set to 1
  wordCount["Apple"] = 1;
  // Object is now { Apple: 1 }
} else {
  // On 3rd iteration, wordCount.Apple will already be 1, so we'll increment to 2
  wordCount["Apple"] = wordCount["Apple"] + 1;
  // Object is now { Apple: 2, Banana: 1 }
}
return wordCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function countWords(arr) {
     const yourObject = new Object();
     let value = inputWords.reduce((a,val,index) => {
          if(index==1){
               yourObject[a]=1;
          }
          if (val in yourObject){
               yourObject[val]=++yourObject[val];
          }else{
               yourObject[val]=1;
          }
           });
     return yourObject;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).